# Embedded video and drop down menu overlay issue

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a page (http://www.stc.ac.uk/content/school-leavers-6th-form/hairdressing) with an embedded video below a drop down menu, on hover of about us the drop down menu goes behind the video in IE but goes on top in safair, firefox and chrome. I have a z-index on the menu's drop and wmode="transparent" on the embed content and it is still going behind in IE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/

Comment: note: the problem seems to happen on chrome18/macos too.

Comment: try wmode="opaque" instead of wmode="transparent"

Answer (score 0):

Just having a Z-index value isn't enough. Try adding position: relative; to the menu's container and see if that helps.